# Generalizing data access in the model. Way to avoid the macro?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, macros

I've written a QAbstractItemModel subclass that works with any data through controller access.
Basically - controller is an abstract interface that actual templated classes derive from. To provide access functions for controller I am creating a series of lambda-based getters/setters like:

```
holder->AddGetter(QPair<int,int>(0,0),
                          [] (const Builtin* data)
{
    if(data)
        return QVariant(data->uml);
    else
        return QVariant();
}
);
holder->AddSetter(QPair<int,int>(0,0),
                          [] (Builtin* data, QVariant value)
{
    if(data)
        data->uml = value.toString();
}
);
holder->AddGetter(QPair<int,int>(1,0),
                              [] (const Builtin* data)
{
    if(data)
        return QVariant(data->cpp);
    else
        return QVariant();
}
);
holder->AddSetter(QPair<int,int>(1,0),
                          [] (Builtin* data, QVariant value)
{
    if(data)
        data->cpp= value.toString();
}
);
....
holder->AddGetter(QPair<int,int>(N,0),
                              [] (const Builtin* data)
....
```

This does solve generalization problem but looks *really* ugly and hard to consume in code, so I had to create a macro:

```
#define ADD_STRING_GETSET(X,Y,Z)  \
X->AddGetter(QPair<int,int>(Y,0), \
[] (const Builtin* data) \
{ \
    if(data) \
        return QVariant(data->Z); \
    else \
        return QVariant(); \
} \
); \
X->AddSetter(QPair<int,int>(Y,0), \
[] (Builtin* data, QVariant value) \
{ \
    if(data) \
        data->Z = value.toString(); \
} \
); \
```

Now I can write:

```
ADD_STRING_GETSET(holder, 0, firstParam);
....
ADD_STRING_GETSET(holder, N, NthParam);
```

but ... well, it's a macro...

Was there a way to solve unwieldiness of the original approach without a macro?

Comment: A great alternative to macros is called a "function".

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass a pointer-to-member function, or another lambda, to a replacement function in order to access the `NthParam` - which is just as ugly.

I have some very similar code, and I opted to use macros.  They are generally frowned upon because they hard to debug, easy to get wrong, and can cause code bloat - but if you happy your macro won't throw up those problems, there is nothing wrong with them in C++.